# Como criar função em PHP para recuperar password?

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu uso 2 páginas, uma para inserir o email (`forgotPassword.php`) que ainda só tem o design gráfico. E a `recuperar.php` que servirá para o utilizador mudar a sua password.

A minha tabela de utilizadores (para onde vai o pessoal registrado) tem as colunas `ID`, `Nome`, `password`, `Email`, `Telemovel`, e `idUtilizador`.

Preciso de uma função em PHP que resete a senha do usuário e o permita alterar a mesma.

**PS:** A minha base de dados é MySQLi.

Comment: Poste um exemplo do que vc tentou.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert expressão correta. Sem erros de sintaxe.

Comment: Eu tentei vários tutoriais no google, não vou pôr aqui todas as formas que tentei...

Comment: A tabela de utilizadores não tem a coluna senha?

Comment: Você deve desenvolver um script para isso, não existe um tutorial que lhe dirá como fazer. Na página `recuperar.php` deve receber no mínimo o e-mail, você precisa verificar se ele existe na base de dados. Se existir você envia um e-mail para ele com uma página criada para gerar nova senha. Seria importante gerar um hash com prazo de vencimento da url que você irá verificar ao abrir e nesta tela você deve permitir que ele mude a senha. Como nosso colega Wallace disse, você deve criar a lógica que mais se adequar à solução do seu problema.

Comment: Hmmm entendi... Que código e utilizado para enviar emails?

Comment: @Bruny dê uma olhada nesse tutorial -> http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/ está bem explicado e simples de entender.